# Get PMK from Handshake

Tags: network, wifi, wpa2

Is there a way to get the PMK from a .cap file containing the 4-way-handshake of a wifi network.
I want to get it to compare it with a long list containing pre-compiled PMKs

Comment: If PMK was there in .cap file i wouldn't have to use wordlist to comapare. I would just look into the file.

Answer (score 1):

No, the PMK is not transmitted on the four-way handshake, yet you can generate your own and use the ANonce, SNonce, and MIC from any handshake to verify if it matches.

The Pre-compiled PMK list is for an specific SSID since that is the variable that changes in generating it with the *Password Based Key Derivative Function 2* (PBKDF2) so unless that list is of the SSID you're trying to get the the PMK, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

The pairwise master key (PMK) is never transmitted. if you are against a WPA-PSK personal (pre-shared key) network you can try to brute-force it offline by using the handshake, however since the pre-shared key can be from 8 to 63 characters in length, it depends on your dictionary and it can be considered `computationally` impossible to crack if 63 characters are used and the pass is of good complexity.

for more information reference:
https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=cracking_wpa